# using mongoose population in Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

There a lot of great examples in adding data in Schemas using population

But how to use this in Express including evaluation existing data and error handling? I already create an user but now I want to add a log to a existing user.

This is my Schema:

```html
const logSchema = new Schema({
    logTitle: String,
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
    }
   });

const userSchema = new Schema({
    
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    } 
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
mongoose.model('Logs', logSchema);
```

Despite all the good examples I lost my way. It 's hard to use the [nice examples](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/) in good working Express code.

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Log1 = mongoose.model('Logs');


const logCreate = function (req, res) {
    const userid = req.params.userid;
    Log1.create({
        logTitle: req.body.logTitle,
        postedBy: userid._id
    });

module.exports = {logCreate
};
```

Do I first create a new log in 'Logs' and then evaluate the existing user? Can somebody give me a push in the right direction? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an objectid to the `postedBy` field. Let's say you have the following routes:

```
router
  .route('/logs/')
  .get(ctrlLogs.logsGetAll)
  .post(ctrlLogs.logsAddOne);

router
  .route('/logs/:logid')
  .get(ctrlLogs.logsGetOne);
```

Then we can define the controller functions as (this is `ctrlLogs`):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Log = mongoose.model('Log');

module.exports.logsAddOne = (req, res) => {
  Log.create({
    logTitle: req.body.logTitle,
    postedBy: req.body.postedBy
  }, (err, newLog) => {
    let response = {};
    if (err) response = { status: 500, message: err };
    else response = { status: 201, message: newLog };

    return res.status(response.status).json(response.message);
  });
};

module.exports.logsGetAll = (req, res) => {
  Log
    .find({})
    .populate('postedBy')
    .exec((err, logs) => {
      let response = {};
      if (err) response = { status: 500, message: err };
      else if (!logs) response = { status: 404, message: [] };
      else response = { status: 200, message: logs };

      return res.status(response.status).json(response.message);
    });
};

module.exports.logsGetOne = (req, res) => {
  Log
    .findById(req.params.logid)
    .populate('postedBy')
    .exec((err, log) => {
      let response = {};
      if (err) response = { status: 500, message: err };
      else if (!log) response = { status: 404, message: `Log with id ${req.params.logid} not found.` };
      else response = { status: 200, message: log };

      return res.status(response.status).json(response.message);
    });
};
```

I've removed a lot of whitespace and curly braces for brevity. You should also not create stuff with values directly from `req.body` or query directly with `req.params.logid`; the values have to be validated first. You can use a library such as [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) for validation.

We can see that by posting a request to */logs* with the following request body:

```
{
    "logTitle": "test log 32",
    "postedBy": "5a2d1ec83ef998431c726dfc"
}
```

we will create a log where the user with id *5a2d1ec83ef998431c726dfc* is set as the postedBy user. If I get */logs/5a2d240c66d7b473a0aa6ec8* (the new log) I get:

```
{
    "_id": "5a2d240c66d7b473a0aa6ec8",
    "logTitle": "test log 32",
    "postedBy": {
        "_id": "5a2d1ec83ef998431c726dfc",
        "firstName": "test",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

We can see that the populated log returns the user as well.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I am now going to try to use this. Is it ok if I have questions that I ask (in reply)?

Comment: @Tichel Yes, sure.

Comment: Thank you so much! At this moment creating users and logs are happy. Later more tests